# Get database address with Docker

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, docker, mariadb

I use docker-compose with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
web_db:
   image: mariadb:latest
   restart: always
   volumes:
    - ./var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
   environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: X
    MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
    MYSQL_USER: wordpress
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: X
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: X

web_front:
  image: nginx
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - web_fpm
  volumes:
    - ./www:/var/www/html:rw
    - ./etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro

web_fpm:
  build: ./PHP-FPM/
  restart: always
  links:
    - web_db:mysql
  volumes:
    - ./www:/var/www/html
```

When configuring Wordpress (manually downloaded in nginx root directory), I'm asked for the address of the database. I've tried `localhost`, but it doesn't work.

PS: I know there are Wordpress images for Docker, but they have the full stack (nginx + PHP) and I don't like it, so don't propose them. ;)

Answer (score 0):

edit:  You will want to put in the IP of the host machine along with port 3306 and here is why.

When starting a container with Docker it is started using an IP assigned from the Docker.  These are all accessible to docker via the docker0 bridged network.  Docker in turn makes those accessible to the host machine by bridging the docker0 NIC on the host machine with the host machines eth0/1 ect.

When you `EXPOSE` a port explicitly via `docker run -td -p <some external port>:<some internal port>` Docker opens that port up in the host IPTables so it is accessible on the local network.  If you do not explicitly open the port but it is exposed in the container (the docker file will say `EXPOSE 3306` for MySQL in its Dockerfile.) then the container is only available to the machine.

Now, when working with Docker containers it's important to know this because when you do a `link` with docker-compose you are only telling that container where another container is on the local docker network.  This only helps if you have containers that start and are looking for a dependent container.

To summarize, when containers are started they are started with a Docker IP that **is only used by Docker** and bridged back to the host machine via docker0, and this is key.  Docker isolates those IP and forces you to either open the ports on the machine to access via your local network.

Back to your question and why you need to pass it the host IP and port 3306.
You need to do this because you are making making a request on your network.  If you put in `localhost` it will not work because the container is not really running on `localhost` it's running on some `172.17.42.x` address so telling WordPress it's on `localhost`, it's not.  It is however on at the host machines IP because the host machine is bridged to `docker0`.  This is why you have to give it the host machines IP.  Because you network can't resolve the 172.17 address since that is specific to Docker and specific to that machines containers.  This is very fundamental to Docker networking and important to understand. See [this article](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/) for more information.

Comment: My iptables are very restrictive, so I'd like to avoid using external IP. And I'm not sure it's the proper way to do it.

Comment: i clarified my answer further to better explain what is happening with docker0 and Docker networking.  Also, yes, this is the proper way to do it, I can speak from experience.  I currently run over 90 containers in a production environment.  You are not exposing these containers to the internet or outside You may also want to watch this video to better understand what docker is doing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UV3cw4QLJLs

Comment: I tried with `external-IP:3306`, but then I get a time-out error (504 Gateway time-out)

Comment: You may need to expose that port in your `docker-compose` file like you did with the `80:80`.  Once you've done that you should be able to connect to the database.  A majority of the time if you cannot connect it's because the port isn't open.  Open the port, retry and let me know if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'web_db' instead of localhost

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried `web_web_db_1` (name given by `docker ps -a`), or adding `:3306` (port also given by `ps -a`), but no chance. I've also add a link to `web_db:mysql` in `web_front` in the `docker-compose.yml`, but no chance.

Comment: it wont work because *you need to expose 3306 on the host machine* like you did port 80 for the web server.  otherwise all requests to 3306 will be blocked by your machines firewall and iptables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference `mysql` because in your compose file you have linked your container to the web_db container and given it an alias of 'mysql'. The web_fpm container will have a record in it's hosts file for mysql which will point to the web_db container.

Alternatively, if you just want to get the ip to enter manually, just run `docker inspect <web_db_container_id>`

Comment: How can I reference it?

Comment: when it asks you for the address of your database just put mysql because inside your web-fpm container, http: //mysql (minus the space) is mapped to the ip of your web_db container

Comment: you need to give a bit more info than doesn't work :p! what doesn't work? what error are you getting?

Comment: why don't you use docker exec <container_id> bash to open a terminal session in your web_fpm container. Then cat the /etc/hosts file to see what aliases it has set up. 

Or you could try the alternative solution mentioned in my answer?

Comment: With `docker exec cat /etc/hosts` on web_fpm, I have:
`172.17.0.2      mysql 6f7d60d63ae5 web_web_db_1` and `172.17.0.2      web_db_1 6f7d60d63ae5 web_web_db_1`, wich is coherent with the result of `docker inspect`. But when trying with `mysql` in the wordpress conf, I still have the same error ("Error when connectig to the database"). As I'm sure of the other informations (name, password, id), I guess it's the database address that is wrong.

Comment: you need to expose the relevant port in your docker compose file to make it available to other containers. so for the web_db, try exposing 3306. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose though to be honest i would of the base image would take care of that

Comment: This doesn't work because the ip listed in the container is the docker ip given to the container from docker. That ip is not accessible outside of that machine.

Comment: It is accessible to linked containers as per the docker compose documentation